# No userstate context is available google cloud dataflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stateful

I am trying to run a stateful aggregating DoFn on google cloud dataflow which references stateful DoFns in its capability matrix, however I get the following error:

> Exception: Requested execution of a stateful DoFn, but no user state context is available. This likely means that the current runner
>   does not support the execution of stateful DoFns.

The preceding error occurs here:

```
@with_input_types(Dict[K, V])
@with_output_types(Dict[K, V])
class StatefulCombineDoFn(beam.DoFn):

    BUFFER = BagStateSpec(
        'buffer', 
        PickleCoder()
    )

    STATE = CombiningValueStateSpec(
        'state', 
        PickleCoder(), 
        CombineFn()
    )

    EXPIRY_TIMER = TimerSpec(
        'expiry', 
        TimeDomain.WATERMARK
    )

    def process(
            self, 
            element,
            w=beam.DoFn.WindowParam,
            buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER),
            state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(STATE),
            expiry_timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(EXPIRY_TIMER)
    ):

                expiry_timer.set(w.end+self.allowed_lateness)
                buffer.add(event)
                state.add(event)

    @on_timer(EXPIRY_TIMER)
    def expiry(
        self,
        state=beam.DoFn.StateParam(STATE),
        buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER)
    ):

            events = buffer.read()
            info = state.read()

            yield [(info, events)]
```

How does one circumnavigate this?

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow now supports user state for streaming pipelines in Python. This is via a new feature that you can activate with `--experiments use_runner_v2`, which uses a new architecture for parts of the Dataflow worker.

The Runner V2 feature will soon be the default, and all pipelines will support user state by default.

**Note**: To allow user state in Batch pipeline, please contact Dataflow support to have your project include that feature.

Comment: Do you have a rough time estimate for when this would be available with dataflow?

Comment: Are there any updates regarding this? Is Dataflow supporting this feature?